# Change size of the box in a Checkbox in Excel with ActiveX controls?

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex, vba

I have this ActiveX checkbox in Excel and I want to change the size of the box.

[image]

I know I can do this if I lock it to a cell and change the cell size. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Shape.ScaleHeight, Shape.ScaleWidth Methods

```
Sub ChangeShapeSize()
Dim Ht As Single, Wd As Single

    Ht = 1.75
    Wd = 2.75

    With Worksheets(1).Shapes("CheckBox1")
        .ScaleHeight Ht, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleWidth Wd, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example on a checkbox?

Comment: I added an example to my original post, if this works for you could you please mark as answered? Thanks

Comment: This scales the frame of the checkbox and not the checkbox shape itself